# Multiple dynamic CSS classes applied based on attributes

Tags: lightning-aura-components, javascript

I want to dynamically add a CSS class to an element based on attribute values.

```
<aura:attribute name="myBool1" type="Boolean" />
<aura:attribute name="myBool1FlagSet" type="Boolean" />

<aura:attribute name="myBool2" type="Boolean" />
<aura:attribute name="myBool2FlagSet" type="Boolean" />
```

The ternary operator allows for three conditions:

```
<section class="{!v.bool1 : 'myClass1' ? 'myClass2'}">
    <!-- my HTML content for this section -->
</section>
```

What I'm trying to do is pass multiple conditions into the ternary operator but I'm unclear how with the syntax, or it's allowed. The equivalent of the following `if/else` statement:

```
if (myBool1 && myBool1FlagSet) {
  class = 'myClass1';
} else {
  class = 'myClass2';
}
if (myBool2 && myBool2FlagSet) {
  class= 'myClass3';
} else {
  class = 'myClass4';
}
```

Can this level of complexity be passed into the ternary operator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Conditional chains](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator) are supported with ternary operators:

```
function example(…) {
    return condition1 ? value1
         : condition2 ? value2
         : condition3 ? value3
         : value4;
}

// Equivalent to:

function example(…) {
    if (condition1) { return value1; }
    else if (condition2) { return value2; }
    else if (condition3) { return value3; }
    else { return value4; }
}
```

however, applying it directly in the class attribute seems a bit heavy, might as well do this in your helper, and create an attribute for your class